# DragDrop module problems with v.7.1.1 highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, dragdropmodule

I have some issues getting the draggable-points module to work.
I’m trying to enable the draggableY property, but for some strange reason it wont work in my highchart-graph.

I have a created a normal highchart with some random points, and my mission is to make it possible to move the points when I click on them.

A sample of what i did is as shown below:

```
chartOptions:{plotOptions:{series:{dragDrop:{draggableY:true}}}}
```

I got highcharts v7.1.1 and the draggable-points module is version3.

Comment: Hi @Roble Noor, Everything seems to work as expected in this live example with Highcharts v7.1.1: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6umtrwkn/ Could you adapt the demo to show the problem?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, i noticed u did not use the chartOptions in the beginning. May that be an issue that i start with the options?

Comment: chartWidget.plotOptions= {series:{dragDrop:{draggableY:true}}};

This is the hard-code version of what i'm trying to perform. I also have a version with chartOptions

chartWidget.chartOptions.plotOptions= {series:{dragDrop:{draggableY:true}}};

Comment: In what environment do you use Highcharts? Do you use any external wrapper for it?

Comment: @ppotaczek Thanks for the help! Found the solution. Imported the modules from a HTML code, and the dragDrop was not included in the code.